# Error in neurons[[i]] %*% weights[[i]] : requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments

Tags: r, neural-network

Have encountered this error whilst trying to train a neural network with R neuralnet package, I have 716 input variables that are either 1 or 0 and I am trying to predict a column that is also 1 or 0. I have looked around and so far this error appears to be caused by a non numeric value but all my values are numeric, so what is the possible problem?

Here is the code

```
train <- read.csv("training.csv")
n <- names(train)
f <- as.formula(paste("conclusion ~", paste(n[!n %in% "conclusion"], collapse = " + ")))
nn <- neuralnet(f, data=train, hidden = 1, threshold=0.4)
```

Here is the output of paste
      conclusion ~ not + work + virus + me + have + down + sick + outbreak + 
      tabs + pill + pills + dont + do + n.t + fall + falling + 
      fell + study + school + fever + again + symptom + why + bird + 
      bad + shot + ill + return + cough + throat + soar + itch...........

Comment: Mm, maybe, you have `logical` type? Provide a code, how do you set/read the data (e.g., read.csv or smth. else...)

Comment: Using read.csv, checked data type with str(data) and confirm it is numeric  see code in edit above

Comment: We need to know what `paste` produces and the data.

Comment: Have added the output of paste